# ResourceDictionaries - StaticResource - other assembly

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm currently trying to figure out how I can get the WPF designer to display correctly a list of resources I can use.

For example when using a `TextBlock` in xaml, I can "preview" the useable resources, for usual.

[image]

This does not seem to work well when using it from an external DLL/assembly (binary).

[image]

I've already tried to use the usual source strings for `ResourceDictionary`,

```
<ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MyAssembly;component/Themes/Generic.xaml"/>
<ResourceDictionary Source="/MyAssembly;component/Themes/Generic.xaml"/>
```

as mentioned in various other questions and answers while googling this issue, though not even the direct `Uri` to the required `ResourceDictionary` seems to work.

**Is there any fix for this issue or does it simply not work ?**
*I don't want to disable the designer, please do not suggest so.*